# Invoking installed mobile facebook app(Any platform android, iphone, bb e.t.c) from html or javascript code/page running on same device?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

I'm wondering if it is possible to invoke installed Facebook and twitter mobile app on any platform either Android, i-phone, BB e.t.c. thru some html/java script /jquery code.

for e.g.

```
<a href="mailto:xxx@abc.com?subject=Hello World">Open Email</a>
```

Hope i'm clear to you all.

Any code-snippet would highly be appreciated.

*mrana*

Answer (score 0):

Well, in android is posible:

When we click on a link the browser sends an intent to the OS.

Check this article for more information:

http://blog.jayway.com/2009/09/24/the-browsable-category-revealed/

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for multi-platform solution for my web app which is developed using above mentioned ingredients. And as it is simple web app which can run on any platform that's why i need a solution for invoking respective facebook/twitter app installed with some global code, same way as we can use tel:1234, mailto: tags of html and they work for any damn platforms.